# Notepad ++ remove return and ad new line after every 150 characters

Tags: notepad++

I have a block of 1,000 characters (numbers) with 20 lines of 50 characters per line and a return at the end of each line.

I want to use notepad ++ to:

- remove the line break at the end of each line; and
- break the digits into individual new lines after each 150 characters

A very basic, step-by-step list of instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-H to bring up the "Replace" dialog.  Select "Extended" under Search Mode.  Put "\r" in the "Find what", and put nothing at all in "Replace with".  That will replace returns with nothing.  Hit "Replace all".  (If you also need to remove newlines, repeat these steps with "\n" as well.)

At this point, you'll have nothing but the numbers in your file.  You have a couple of options:

- you could just set the cursor to position 150 (using the mouse or arrow keys) and then hit Enter, move to the next line, and repeat.
- you could also set the cursor at the very beginning of the file, start recording a macro, press the right arrow 150 times, press enter, move to the next line, press the Home key, and stop recording the macro.  You would then re-apply the macro until the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

With only the window Replace:

1. Type `\r\n` in the field 'Find', after selecting mode "Extended". I assume there that you edit a text file with Windows EOL convention. Remove any character present in the field 'Replace with'. Press Replace All -> all characters are on a single line
2. Select mode "Regular expression". Type `(.{150})` in the field "Find" and `\1\r\n` in the field "Replace with". Press button Replace All -> all is ok.

The second step uses regular expressions. The first one describes a chain of exactly 150 characters; in the second one, `\1` is the matched chain. So basically it selects 150 characters and append a line break.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in one step:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.{50})\R(.{50})\R`  or `^(\d{50})\R(\d{50})\R` if the lines contain ONLY digits.
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
(.{50})     : group 1, 50 any character but newline
\R          : any kind of linebreak
(.{50})     : group 2, 50 any character but newline
\R          : any kind of linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1
$2          : content of group 2
```